# NoMethodError in ArticlesController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I known had the same question with the above title, but it also cannot resolved my problem. I am practicing with Rails :[Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and when I tried **Updating Articles** in this tutorial I got the error below (`NoMethodError in ArticlesController#edit`):

[image: Errors]

Here is the **controller** file:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :contents)
    end
end
```

and here is the **edit** view

```
<h1>Editing article</h1>
 
<%= form_for :article, url: article_path(@article), method: :patch do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this article from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= f.label :contents %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :contents %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
 
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

**Edit** Here is the **full trace**:

```
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:25:in `edit'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: apparently you are missing an `Article` model. Have you created that? Have you migrated your database?

Comment: Yes, I had **article.rb** file into the models folder

Comment: Here is the contents of article model: **class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5}
end**

Comment: Have you created the controller private method article_params ?

Comment: @Mohanraj I didn't really understand what are you meaning? I have **private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :contents)
    end** into the **controller** file

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate`, after creating the model ?

Comment: Yep, I also run **rake db:migrate**

Comment: click on the full trace link on the error page and show us.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the line from any source ? If so, remove the line and write it manually there. There is a **junk character** I can see.

Comment: I written it by manually. But with the **edit** page's content, I copy and paste it

Comment: @ArupRakshit It looks like it is!

Comment: Which editor you are using... ?

Comment: Just **ON** the junk character option in your editor.. You can see..

Comment: It looks like got the solution. @arup i also had the same problem because of the copy paste.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I didn't understand the meaning of **ON the junk character option in your editor**. What action I need to do with my editor?

Comment: @Mohanraj What is your solution?

Comment: @lee Read this - *for junk one*, https://forums.adobe.com/message/4932404

Comment: @lee, just add a new file, put the logic into it, whatever you have. But *DONT COPY PASTE*. Manually write it. Then *REMOVE* the current file and add this one. Run it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lee`, do this:

```
def edit
   @article = Article.find params[:id]
end
```

My system uses ascii, so the above text should be error-free (as per `@Arup`'s comment)

Considering you have `article.rb` set up with `Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base`, I don't see why this would not work?

Comment: Rich I am 100% sure. There is a junk character inserted. You can see in the error message. It is coming as -> **`** <-.

Comment: Yep me too - it wouldn't just post that

Comment: Arup Rakshit you right.I copy-paste with commands **def edit
   @article = Article.find params[:id]
end**

Comment: And the problem is I have '..' before the command: **@article = Article.find params[:id]** . Like that: **..@article = Article.find params[:id]** but with TextWrangler editor I cannot see it. And the problem just found when I open it with Xcode editor.